# Can someone explain the 'this' in debounce function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, debouncing

With this `debounce` function:

```
function debounce(fn, delay) {
    var timer
    return function () {
      var context = this
      var args = arguments
      clearTimeout(timer)
      timer = setTimeout(function () {
        fn.apply(context, args)
      }, delay)
    }
  }
```

can someone explain why I should use `fn.apply(context,args)` instead of `fn()` only?

I know `.apply` will change the context and `var context = this` will make the context always be the same as the context in `fn()`. I can't find a scenario where using `fn()` and `fn.apply(context, args)` gives a different result.

Can someone give me an example?

Comment: You have to do this, obviously, because you want to execute function in a caller context. https://javascript.info/

Comment: You could not use debounce to decorate an object method otherwise.

Comment: You don't need to use `this` or `apply` unless your are using classes/prototypes/object methods. If you don't use `this` you can just do what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the following class:

```
class Foo {
  constructor () {
    this.a = 'a';
    this.bar = debounce(this.bar, 500);
  }

  bar () {
    console.log(this.a);
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();
foo.bar();
foo.bar();
foo.bar();
```

So what gets logged, and when, and how many times? You are going to see one value logged, one time, about half a second after the last call. With the definition you posted you'll see `a`. If you omit the contextual part you'll see `undefined`:

```
function debounceWithoutCtx(fn, delay) {
    var timer
    return function (...args) {
      clearTimeout(timer)
      timer = setTimeout(function () {
        fn(...args)
      }, delay)
    }
 }
```